# next.js 13 debugging the loading.js UI

Tags: next.js, browser, next.js13

According to:
Nextjs documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VIy5.png)

i created a loading.js file for the page.

**what i want to do?**
I want to be able to debug loading.js of any page without having to import it in a test page as a component.

**why i can't do it?**
when developing the nextjs app since the app runs locally i barely see the loading UI because the page loads really quick. (bandwith throttling doesn't really help for this)

Is there any smart&easy technique to do that? Like stopping the network transaction of the browser etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug the `LoadingSkeleton`, you could insert it in a page. If you really want to check the `loading.js`, you could call an API route that waits for a long time before returning something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug following the advice [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/loading). Using React developer tools you can manually toggle the loading state